# Excel - Merge Multiple Columns Cells into a single Cell

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet in the usual fashion. That is to say, rows and columns. So if there are seven rows, each column has seven values. I want to take one of these columns and make it extend down across the whole spreadsheet. TRANSFORMATION (LOGIC) used to have seven values, now it has one. How do I do this? EDIT: By "down across", I mean the column should have just one cell.

[image]

Comment: Slightly confused on my first read: extend "down across"? Just want to clarify how you want it to look

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I mean the column should have only one cell, as opposed to have seven cells like all the others.

Comment: I hope I am understanding your question correctly with my answer but if not I apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the merging of your cells, select the desired cell range on your sheet and then you will click the "Merge" button found on the Home tab in Excel.

[image]Note that if the content is already in the cells it will take the value from the first cell which has content in it already, so best to copy your values and such out first if you would like to preserve them.